# JQuery does not find textarea value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have a textarea in my HTML file, and I want to send its content to the console.
Here the code:

```
<p class="i_link">Link:</p>
<textarea name="link" id="Story_Link" cols="100" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<!--!name-->
<p class="i_name">Name:</p>
<textarea name="name" id="Story_Name" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<!--!number-->
<p class="i_number">Number:</p>
<textarea name="number" id="Story_Number" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<!--!author-->
<p class="i_author">Author:</p>
<textarea name="author" id="Story_Author" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
​
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
​
<script>
function myFunction() {
   console.log('hello ' + $('i_link').val())
}
</script>
```

But it prints out `hello undefined` to the console.
I expected to get the value of my textarea instead of undefined.

How to get the expected output?

Comment: You are missing a `.` (dot) in the selector, `i_link` should be `.i_link`.

Comment: @marekful where?

Comment: The beauty of jquery is that it allowed css-like class and id selectors (before they were supported in later JavaScript iterations). `$('#wrapper')` get the element with the id wrapper, `$('.layout')` get all elements with the class name layout.

Comment: now don't send nothing

Comment: And the terrible thing about jQuery is how much it's used for trivial operations that don't warrant it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus and how I can use only javascript to send to console the textarea value?

Comment: val is used to get the value of some input, text, checkbox, textarea etc, but you don't have an input with the class name you are trying to target. I am going out on a limb and suspect you want this: `$('#Story_Link').val();`

Comment: @lharby thanks, it works!

Comment: You should vote on one of the answers below. They are more thorough.

Comment: See my answer below for a "vanilla" JavaScript example. You don't need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your line

```
console.log('hello ' + $('i_link').val())
```

with

```
console.log('hello ' + $('#Story_Link').val())
```

---

You tried to get the value from a `<p>` tag and you missed the `.` class selector.

My solution will lookup for your Story_Link textarea I used the hash sign for finding that textarea by id.

Here you will find more information about how to find elements in HTML DOM with jquery:

- Select elements by class https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
- Select elements by id https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
- Every kind of selectors in jquery https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

---

Here I got you a working example:

```js
function myFunction() {
   console.log('hello ' + $('#Story_Link').val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="i_link">Link:</p>
<textarea name="link" id="Story_Link" cols="100" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<!--!name-->
<p class="i_name">Name:</p>
<textarea name="name" id="Story_Name" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<!--!number-->
<p class="i_number">Number:</p>
<textarea name="number" id="Story_Number" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<!--!author-->
<p class="i_author">Author:</p>
<textarea name="author" id="Story_Author" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your answer here meaningless. Just include your code in a "stack snippet" (the `{}` button while you are editing) and it will run right here. Also, PLEASE don't advocate W3 Schools, which is widely known to have incomplete, out of date, or flat out wrong information. The Mozilla Developer Network ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)) is really one of ***the*** authoritative places for comprehensive info. on almost all web technologies.

Comment: Is that actual a thing? I saw this in many postes before. I will update my answer and fix that. Thanks for that hints.

Comment: @ScottMarcus good hint. I adjusted my code example and used a code snippet here on SO. I wasn't aware of this great functionality. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you haven't supplied a CSS selector to the jQuery object that matches an element and so it's not finding any element to get the value of. If you are trying to get the Author name, you need to pass `#Story_Author` because that is the `id` of the `textarea` where that data is entered.

```html
    <p class="i_link">Link:</p>
    <textarea name="link" id="Story_Link" cols="100" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <!--!name-->
    <p class="i_name">Name:</p>
    <textarea name="name" id="Story_Name" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <!--!number-->
    <p class="i_number">Number:</p>
    <textarea name="number" id="Story_Number" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <!--!author-->
    <p class="i_author">Author:</p>
    <textarea name="author" id="Story_Author" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   console.log('hello ' + $('#Story_Author').val())
}
</script>
```

But, you have quite a few issues beyond that.

jQuery is a powerful JavaScript library that can make doing very complex things much simpler. When it was first introduced, the core JavaScript language as well as the DOM API weren't as mature as they are now and so even relatively simple queries in "vanilla" JavaScript were cumbersome. That's not the case any longer and, as such, the need for jQuery to do these trivial tasks is gone. For what you are doing, jQuery is only making things more complex. Here's all you need to do this without jQuery:

```html
<p class="i_link">Link:<br>
<input id="Story_Link"></p>

<p class="i_name">Name:<br>
<input id="Story_Name"></p>

<p class="i_number">Number:<br>
<input id="Story_Number"></p>

<p class="i_author">Author:<br>
<input id="Story_Author"></p>
<button>Click me</button>

<script>
  // Get references to any elements you'll reference more than once, just once
  const link = document.getElementById("Story_Link");
  const name = document.getElementById("Story_Name");
  const number = document.getElementById("Story_Number");
  const author = document.getElementById("Story_Author");

  // Do your event binding in JavaScript, not HTML
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
   console.log('Hello ' + author.value + " Here are your details:");
   console.log("\tStory Link: " + link.value);
   console.log("\tStory Name: " + name.value);
   console.log("\tStory Number: " + number.value);  
  });
</script>
```

As you'll see from above, the HTML is much simpler, there's no need to reference jQuery, and the pure JavaScript is also very simple.

**Additionally:**

- A `<textarea>` is used for multi-line input. When you just have a
  short string to collect, `<input>` is the correct element to use.
- `type="text/javascript"` has not been needed in `script` elements for
  quite a few years now.
- You really shouldn't end your paragraphs and then have related
  content below them that uses a break to separate itself from the next
  paragraph. Paragraphs are for complete thoughts. See the updated HTML
  in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script code to following

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   console.log('hello ' + $('#Story_Author').val())
}
</script>
```

notice that . in `$('._link)`
while using jquery you have to pass selector of class or id
for class you have to add . at start
and for id you have to add # at the start

example:
to select element with id myId

```
$('#myId')
```

to select element with class myClass

```
$('.myClass')
```

Also, the p tag in HTML does not have a value attached to it
if you want to get value in the textarea you should select the id of the testarea

Comment: `.i_link` is a paragraph, which does not have a `value`.

Comment: Your example does not work, thus this does not answer the question properly. It would be outstanding if you reconsider to improve your answer.

Comment: just edited my answer :)
thanks for the feedback
I did not notice that class is attached to the p tag

Answer (score -4):

You want to get value/text from textarea, so you have to write:

```
$('#Story_Link').val()
```

Comment: IMHO you should add some information about what is different between OPs and your code. OP should be able to learn some from your answer.